# Get location of symbols in a.out file

Tags: gcc, symbols, elf, dwarf

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732/how-do-i-list-the-symbols-in-a-so-file) does a great job explaining how to get the symbols (variables, functions, etc) of an elf file.

**Now that I have the symbols I will like to know on what location (module) they are**.

For example if I compile a program that consists of the files `main.c`, `someFile.h` and `someFile.c` . Also let's say that the `main.c` program contains the global variable **int Counter.** then how I be able to tell that variable **Counter** is located in main.c?

Comment: Compile the C files to their respective object files (without linking these object files together). If you were to inspect these object files you will  get your answer.

Comment: most of the files depend on other files so compiling files individually might not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Answer is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11056685/637142).                      .