# objdump/readelf get variables information

Tags: gcc, objdump, readelf, debug-information

I need to get the information about global variables from a compiled c program. I asked a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11056685/637142).

The problem that I have now is that the program where I am trying to extract the variables info is very big and it takes 4 seconds just to get the tree in text (`readelf -w[i] file.out`). Then I have to parse the tree jumping back and forth in order to get to the place that I need. For example if a variable is of type `const unsigned char * volatile MyVariable` then I will have to navigate to 5 different nodes of the tree and if the program contains 1000 variables then it takes a while to get what I need.

**So my question is** how can I make better use of the readelf command to achieve what I need. The `readelf -w[i] file.out` command gives me way more information that I need (every function, subrutine, local variable, etc). For example instead of going over the output of that command to get the global variables I use the `readelf -s --wide file.out` command to get just the variables. that command will just give me the name of the variables so I will still have to look in the tree to see if a variable is an integer for example.

On page 237 of [this link](http://dwarfstd.org/doc/DWARF4.pdf) I belive there is an example of how to get info about a type for example. Here is a pic:

[image]

I am taking about 15 seconds to parse what I need and still have several bugs. It will be nice if I don't have to reinvent the wheel and make better use of the readelf command.

Comment: Have you solved this?  Are you just trying to make your parsing/extracting information from `readelf` faster?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Andy Wingo's new [dltool](http://wingolog.org/archives/2012/06/19/dltool-mines-dwarf) utility, which does all the parsing the DWARF info for you.

Comment: I need to parse it on windows... I might be able to compile that on windows I will give it a try.